# cypress Cypress.config.baseUrl is set correctly however getting error from cy.visit()

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, base-url, e2e

here is my test:

```
describe('settings page test', () =>{
    it('tests navigation to settings page from login', () =>{
        console.log(Cypress.config().baseUrl)
        cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseurl)
```

the `console.log(Cypress.config().baseUrl)` sure enough is containing the value my baseUrl is set as.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://superniftyurltho.com",
  "env": {

  }
}
```

and here is the error

```
    cy.visit() must be called with a url 
or an options object containing a url as its 1st argumentLearn more
```

anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: There is a difference in upper case "U" - `cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseurl)` should be `cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)`

Answer (score 7):

If you have the `baseUrl` defined in your `cypress.json` you can use the `cy.visit()` in your tests as:

```
cy.visit('/')
```

OR,

If you want to use the `Cypress.config()` method to access the baseUrl from your `cypress.json` you have to use:

```
cy.visit(Cypress.config('baseUrl'))
```

OR,

With your example, the 'u' in the **baseurl** is in lower case, it should be in upper case. Thanks, @Barmy Fotheringay-Phipps and @Aloysius Parker for pointing it out.

```
cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)
```

Comment: `Cypress.config('baseUrl')` returns exactly the same thing as `Cypress.config().baseUrl`

Comment: Also, you don't ***have*** to use `cy.visit('/')` if baseUrl is defined.

Comment: If you visit the `Cypress.config()` docs https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config#Test-Configuration, I cannot see any examples for `Cypress.config().baseUrl`

Comment: Also if you visit https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Usage it states that to visit baseUrl you have to use `cy.visit(‘/‘)`

Comment: Incorrect, it does not say it's mandatory. You can still use `cy.visit(Cypress.config().baseUrl)` and it will correctly go to the baseUrl.

Comment: @AloysiusParker I am unaware of that, can you share the link to the cypress docs where some example is given where I can access `cypress.json` content using `Cypress.config().someKey` ?

Comment: When no arguments are passed in to `Cypress.config()` it returns an object and you can reference properties with dot notation.

Comment: Alapan, it's really easy to confirm - just test it!

Comment: Thanks, @AloysiusParker I just ran it and it worked. Learned something new today. Updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, Javascript is case sensitive so accessing the `baseUrl` property of your config object must use an exact case match,

```js
Cypress.config().baseurl === undefined
```

so

```js
cy.visit(undefined)
```

causes the error **cy.visit() must be called with a url...**

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same issue with the new updates just make sure to add the base url in your cypress.config.js file, then enter the base url inside e2e:

module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8484',
},
})